# How to increment margin value (or any style value) for each element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want left margin of every element in a class to have 70px left margin more than the last one. i.e. marginLeft += 70px;
Here's what I have tried:

```js
function MarginLeftFunc()
    {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('divClass');
    var i;
 
    for(i=0; i<elements.length; i++)
    {
     elements[i].style.marginLeft += 70 + "px";
     console.log(elements[i].style.marginLeft);
    }
    }
window.addEventListener('load', MarginLeftFunc, false);
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="divClass">Div1</div>
 <div class="divClass">Div2</div>
 <div class="divClass">Div3</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Now the console logs exactly 3 elements, which is good, but its not incrementing value of left margin. It set all the element's left Margins to 70px.
It just logs 70px 3 times. I have tried fiddling with variable 'i', inserting multiple loops, but have not found a solution yet. What do i have to do to increment value for each element? And no JQuery.

Comment: Can a pure CSS solution work, or do you want a javascript solution exclusively?

Comment: @Aziz My original code has a lot of elements in class. So css may take a lot of lines, that's why I was using js. But if you have a good css solution, then its alright with css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try use method [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle),

> The Window.getComputedStyle() method gives the values of all the CSS
>   properties of an element after applying the active stylesheets and
>   resolving any basic computation those values may contain.

because `element.style.marginLeft` does not show styles that come from CSS rules.

```js
function MarginLeftFunc() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('divClass');
  var i, marginLeft = 70;

  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    marginLeft += parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(elements[i]).marginLeft, 10) + 70;
    elements[i].style.marginLeft = marginLeft + 'px';
  }
}

window.addEventListener('load', MarginLeftFunc, false);
```

```css
.divClass {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="divClass">Div1</div>
  <div class="divClass">Div2</div>
  <div class="divClass">Div3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```js
function MarginLeftFunc()
{
    var i;
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('divClass');
    var elementStyle = window.getComputedStyle(elements[0]);//gives the style of first element

    var margleft =elementStyle.marginLeft;//get margin left value
     margleft = margleft.replace("px", " ");//remove px
     margleft = parseInt(margleft);//convert string to integer
    for(i=0; i<elements.length; i++)
    {
        margleft+=70;
        elements[i].style.marginLeft = margleft + "px";
        console.log(elements[i].style.marginLeft);
    }
}
window.addEventListener('load', MarginLeftFunc, false);
```

```css
.divClass {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="divClass">Div1</div>
  <div class="divClass">Div2</div>
  <div class="divClass">Div3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain the answer?

Comment: @Mike Antoniadis it does not work correctly, because `elements[i].style.marginLeft` returns empty string and margin must be 80 not 70